# How to insert a record returned by a function into a table

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I have a plpgsql function that takes one input parameter and returns multiple columns of data as a record.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(
    IN id bigint,
    OUT foo bigint,
    OUT bar double precision
    )
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    -- some calculations
    foo = id + 1;
    bar = 42.0;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to execute `my_func` for each row of a table (`table_input`) with the id column as input parameter and insert the returned row into another table (`table_output`).
The table `table_output` has the same columns as the columns return by `my_func`.

How can I do that?

The query

```
SELECT my_func(id) INTO table_output FROM table_input;
```

gives me:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "my_func" has pseudo-type record
> ```

The following query does what I want, but `my_func()` gets called twice per row:

```
INSERT INTO table_output 
SELECT
 (my_func(table_input.id)).foo,
 (my_func(table_input.id)).bar
FROM table_input;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_output SELECT * FROM myfunc(id)`?

Comment: Yes, thank your very much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming current Postgres version 9.5, since it has not been defined.
Best solved with a `LATERAL` join (Postgres 9.3+).

The minimal working form:

```
INSERT INTO table_output
SELECT f.*
FROM   table_input t, my_func(t.id) f;
```

The same, more explicit:

```
INSERT INTO table_output (foo, bar)
SELECT f.foo, f.bar
FROM   table_input t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL my_func(t.id) AS f;
```

Or, since *exactly one result row* is guaranteed in this case, a plain function call in a subquery does the same, probably cheaper:

```
INSERT INTO table_output
SELECT f.*
FROM  (SELECT my_func(id) AS f FROM table_input) t;
```

It's wise to declare target columns in a persisted `INSERT`, even if the row types of function and table currently match. This is more robust against later changes.

`CROSS JOIN LATERAL` is just the verbose equivalent of a simple comma before a set-returning function in the `FROM` list. (Binding more closely, but that's not relevant in this query.)

Detailed explanation for `LATERAL` and ***how to avoid repeated function evaluation*** in this recent, related answer on SO - with links to more:

- [Split function-returned record into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297935/split-function-returned-record-into-multiple-columns/38297985#38297985)